# WPF, Text input, each word as a separate object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have to create a windows app, that is a word processor which suggests user synonyms of the words he typed in. This has to work in a whole document, with multiple sentences, with sugestion generated and shown as a popup, or context menu, only when user right clicks a word. I belive I have to have each word as a separate object, so that I can subscribe to RMBClick event then populate popup and show it. Problem is, I don't know how to make each word user types in, a separate object. Is there a clean solution? I think problem is similar to that of spell checking

Comment: Can you do `Split(' ')` ?

Comment: I mean, what I ment is, given a TextBox (or RichTexBox), with a sentence within it, how do I know what word did user right clicked on? What I thought is to have each word as a separate ui element, so that I can subscribe to it's OnClick event. But I don't know what types of elements to use, and how to process raw user input to make it reliable with text beeing written, deleted and inserted into sentences...

Comment: Pllease get more specific and show which text control you are using

Answer (score 1):

When using `RichTextBox` you can get the `TextPointer` that specifies the closest insertion position for the supplied point by calling `RichTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint`. Inspect the text content using the obtained `TextPointer`.

When using `TextBox` you can get the index of the character that is closest to the specified point by calling `TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint`. Inspect the text content using the obtained index.

Text inspection in this case means find the beginning and the end of the word at the current position/index (word boundaries).